# Performance of different Count patterns

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering

The two pieces of code below are functionally equivalent, and I would have expected similar performance. (The only difference between the two is the form of the pattern used.) But the second piece of code takes substantially longer. Why? (I've done this several times; the spread is never less than about 6 seconds, and usually closer to 10, on approximately a 70 second runtime).

```
Timing[For[i = 1, i < 1000, i++,
      x = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100000];
      Count[x, r_ /; r >= 50]
    ];
]

(* {68.6056, Null}} *)

Timing[For[i = 1, i < 1000, i++,
      x = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100000];
      Count[x, _?(# >= 50 &)]
    ];
]

(* {79.1529, Null} *)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a good reason why it has to be like this.  It just happens to be like this in Mathematica 10.3.  Both constructs involve evaluating some Mathematica code for each element of `x`, and theoretically both could be optimized in various ways ... The code that is being evaluated is clearly different, so it's not that surprising that there is a slight performance difference.

Comment: However, if you want much better performance, use `Total@UnitStep[x - 50]`.  This is of course not nearly as readable as `Count`, and it gets even messier if you change that `>=` to a `>`.  To make it easier to use these constructs I wrote the [BoolEval](http://packagedata.net/index.php/#package-31) package, using which you can do `Total@BoolEval[x >= 50]`.  Also consider using `RepeatedTiming` and really really avoid `For` ... if you need a procedural loop, use `Do`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the tips about `UnitStep` and `RepeatedTiming`. (And, I never use `For`, just for this example).

Comment: @Xavier. You are exactly correct. I retract my comment: I clearly had all kinds of syntax errors. If you define `f` correctly, it doesn't result in a speed-up.

Comment: @Szabolcs However, I do take some issue with your term "slight performance difference". 11 seconds out of 68 is hardly slight...

Comment: @rogerl I was referring to 69 vs 79.